# python pandas: groupby apply function looks at prior rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that I'd like to add a column to representing the results of some calculation (it's complex)  The calc needs to be done at each group, and each row value is dependent on the rows above it.  Here's a simple example of the code I have so far and the desired output:

**Edit 1**
so I've updated my code below, maybe I'm not understanding how apply works, but I thought this would execute twice (once for each group).  Then, my function would loop over each row within those executions.  I'm still puzzled as to why it's going 3 times...I thought "executed" would print 5 times. Thoughts on this?

**Edit 2**
I had the indentation wrong on my return function.  That fixed it.  Thanks for the help!

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'type' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar','bar'], 'cost' : [1, 4, 2, 8,9]})
df['class'] = np.nan

def customFunction(test_df):
    print np.shape(test_df)
    iteration = 1
    for currRow in test_df.iterrows():
        print 'executed'
        if iteration == 1:
            test_df['class'] = 'first'
        else:
            if currRow[1]['cost'] > priorCost:
                test_df['class'] = 'greater'
            elif currRow[1]['cost'] < priorCost:
                test_df['class'] = 'less'
            else:
                test_df['class'] = 'equal'

        iteration += 1        
        priorCost = currRow[1]['cost']

    return test_df

grouped_df = df.groupby(['type']).apply(customFunction)
```

output:

```
(2, 2)
executed
(2, 2)
executed
(3, 2)
executed
   cost type  class
0     1  foo  first
1     4  foo  first
2     2  foo  first
3     8  bar  first
4     9  bar  first
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you as far as I got so far - I need a short break right now, but:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_clipboard())
df.set_index('type', inplace=True)
test = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.cost.diff())
```

gives me (since `diff()` calculates differences within columns w.r.t. the first entry)

```
Out[160]: 
type
bar     type
bar    NaN
bar      1
Name: cost, dtype: ...
foo     type
foo    NaN
foo      3
foo     -2
Name: co...
dtype: object
```

So this contains all the information you need. At the moment, I'm struggling to merge this information back to the original dataframe. `df['differences'] = test` gives a huge mess.

**Update**

I'm almost there:

```
>>> df['differences'] = test[1].append(test[0])
>>> df.loc[df['differences'] > 0, 'inWords'] = 'greater'   
>>> df.loc[df['differences'] < 0, 'inWords'] = 'lesser' 
>>> df.loc[df['differences'].isnull(), 'inWords'] = 'first' 
>>> df
Out[184]: 
      cost  differences  inWords
type                            
foo      1          NaN    first
foo      4            3  greater
foo      2           -2   lesser
bar      8          NaN    first
bar      9            1  greater
```

So, the only thing needed is a generic expression instead of `test[1].append(test[0])`. Perhaps someone else can chip in here?

**Update 2**

Responding to your comment: whenever you define your function for `apply()`, as

```
def compareSomethingWithinAGroup(group):
    someMagicHappens()
    return someValues
```

You have access to all standard pandas functions and the whole group inside the function. So then, you can create all complicated row dependent magic, whatever it may be. The only thing you have to pay attention to: `someValues` needs to be a `Series` or `dataframe` with one column only, that has as much entries as the `group` has rows. As long as you return such `someValues`, you can always do `df['resultOfSomethingComplicated'] = df.groupby(level=0).apply(compareSomethingWithinAGroup)`, and use all rows in your response.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, but the actual calculation I'm doing is different, and much more complicated (I just posted this as an example - if you can calculate row x relative to row x-1, I could transform that into what I actually need to do).  I need to figure out how to compare rows, not do the actual step in the example above.

Comment: I updated my response. Hope that helps? Otherwise, if you need help with something specifically what is supposed to be happening inside that `apply()` function, you need to be more specific on what exactly you try to do.

Comment: Thanks - I updated the code above, I'm still not fully understanding why the results aren't as anticipated...